# remove hashtag in url, make error when refresh f5 (angularJs-cordova)

Tags: angularjs, cordova

i have some question about router in angularJs. i used angular-ui-router. but i get error when removed hashtag(#) in url with $locationProvider. how to fix this problem?, in my module:

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
  $stateProvider

    .state('locale',{
      url: '/locale',
      templateUrl: 'template/static/locale.html'
    })

    .state('callback',{
      url: '/callback',
      templateUrl: 'template/static/callback.html',
      controller: 'userCalendar'
    })

    .state('sign_in',{
      url: '/sign_in',
      templateUrl: 'template/users/sign_in.html'
    })

    .state('addprofile', {
      url: '/addprofile',
      templateUrl: 'template/users/addprofile.html'
    })

    .state('tabs',{
      url: '/tabs',
      templateUrl: 'template/pages/tabs.html'
    })

    .state('tabs.mainMenu', {
      url: '/mainMenu',
      templateUrl: 'template/pages/mainmenu.html'
    })

    .state('form',{
      url: '#/form',
      templateUrl: '/template/users/form.html'
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('locale');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
  });
});
```

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you remove the hash routing you will get this Refresh problem (even without Cordova). I see you already have **$locationProvider** setup with **requireBase** in your `app.js` config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: true});
```

That means you will also need to set the **base URL** in your `index.html`:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>AngularJS</title>
<base href="http://localhost:8888/angularjs-website-folder/">
```

You will also need to config your server url rewrite rules. Here's a solution for MAMP localhost using an `.htaccess` file in website folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /angularjs-website-folder/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt)
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

NB: The first **RewriteBase** should be a relative link whereas the base url in the index.html will be absolute.