# How to configure Jetty's rewrite rules to remove the hashtag from AngularJS URLs?

Tags: angularjs, jetty

I'm building my web apps using AngularJS and as a web server I'm using jetty (java web apps). However, I want to remove the hashtag from the urls. I came across many answers about this topic and they all involved configuring Apache web server to reach the goal. However I couldn't find any solution using jetty. This question ([remove hashtag in url, make error when refresh f5 (angularJs-cordova)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115453/remove-hashtag-in-url-make-error-when-refresh-f5-angularjs-cordova)) mentions the rewrite rules for Apache, but how can I achieve the same behaviour/configuations for jetty?

Comment: Hope this helps https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag